# Pandas is installed but IDLE says module not found - in same directory as other modules

Tags: pandas

Hi I'm fairly inexperienced with installing modules (getting practice now though) I have used pip to install pandas in python 3.5 by

python3.5 -m pip install pandas

but IDLE returns an error "No module named pandas" when I try to import it.

'pip list' shows that it is installed. The go-to answer for this problem seems to be that it is in the wrong directory, but the terminal lists pandas in the exact same file path as all my other modules which do work.

It is installed on the correct version of python, I'm only running 3.5. When I run the pip install command again, or run it for say, numpy, it lists the exact same site-packages folder.

But IDLE will not recognize it.

Anyone have any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: I've never used IDLE but it looks like the problem is python's version. In a typical OSX installation, there is 3-10 python installations of different versions (2.4, 2.6, 2.7, 3.4,...) in different directories. I expect the same for linux. The problem may be that your IDLE is linked to one python installation  (without pandas, numpy) and your terminal is linked to another version (in which you have installed pandas, numpy and so on).

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my previous comment, the problem may be that your IDLE is linked to one python installation (without pandas, numpy) and your terminal is linked to another version (in which you have installed pandas, numpy and so on).

In my terminal

```
> which python
/Users/myname/miniconda3/envs/life3/bin/python

> ls /Users/myname/miniconda3/envs/life3/bin/
   There is indeed idle3 and idle3.6 in the directory
```

But if I start `idle` naively, it will start with another version of python

```
> which idle
/usr/bin/idle  ==> python 2.7
```

You can check the python version in `idle`: `import os; os.path` (for me, it points to the 2.7 system version, not my 3.6 one)
To have the same version as in the terminal

```
> idle3
or
> /Users/myname/miniconda3/envs/life3/bin/idle3
```

Comment: When I use the os.path it lists the same file path as the terminal gives when I ask it to install pandas. Every indication I have is saying they are in the same place. It's becoming very frustrating

Comment: You must be correct that they are seeing different directories, but I'm not sure how to correct this. I'm wondering if uninstalling python completely and reinstalling from the terminal might be my best bet

Comment: You can try: `pip install pandas` then `which python`  to have the directory of python, then call the idle in this directory. In my system, it is `/Users/myname/miniconda3/envs/life3/bin/idle3`

Answer (score 1):

This is a late breaking update; I never managed to direct pip to the correct python. Instead I reinstalled my OS, installed just one version of python (3.6) and I can now install any module very easily using pip. Kind of a hassle but totally worth it to not have to mess around with whatever file path mess I had accidentally created before.

Answer (score 1):

To know your current directory use below code:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

Ideally here is where pandas should be installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue - I would suggest checking whether you are in 32-bit mode or 64-bit more. I had both version installed, and I had installed pandas for 64-bit Python. Thus, when I opened idle in 64-bit mode, it worked for me.